# Batch file doesn't enters if statement

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I'm having problem with a batch file that I wrote, it suppose to detect when a process A isn't running and then kill process B. I check if process A exists with wmic (and loop over it while this is the case) and when I detect that it isn't running I just use taskkill on the other process. The problem is that it doesn't enter the if statement for some reason although the values seem to be equal..

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set EXE=python.exe

    :RUNNERON
    FOR /F "skip=1 delims=" %%x IN ('wmic process where "CommandLine Like '%%some text to match%%' and Caption='python.exe'" get caption') DO for /F "delims=" %%j in ("%%x") do (

        echo Current process name: %%j   :: This prints "python.exe"
        echo Required process is: %EXE%  :: This prints "python.exe"
        IF %%j == %EXE% (
            echo inside if
            goto RUNNERON
        ) ELSE (
            echo inside else
        )
    )
    echo Runner is done - killing watchdog process
    taskkill /F /im "pythonw.exe"

    pause
```

In task manager I have the python.exe process that matches the wmic condition up and running so it should be stuck in the loop but for some reason, the "inside else" is being printed to the console, I dont know what I'm doing wrong, it seems like it something in the way I compare the two..

Thank you

EDIT: 
I solved it, the problem was in the "delims" in the first for loop.. once I removed it everything worked fine.
So to conclude - this is the working "for" line:

```
FOR /F "skip=1" %%x IN ('wmic process where "CommandLine Like '%%forking import main%%' and Caption='python.exe'" get caption') DO for /F "delims=" %%j in ("%%x") do (
```

Comment: A couple of tips: probably better to use `if /i "%%j" == "%exe%" ...`. The `/i` means case-insensitive (just in case), and putting double-quotes around each side protects you if ever either side is an empty string (probably not the problem here). In case there are stray spaces (as a deleted answer suggested), use something like `echo Current process is :%%j:` (with colons immediately either side of the value being printed) so you can see if there are stray spaces (and the same for `%EXE%`).

Answer (score 1):

The most important part of your script:

```bat
FOR /F "skip=1 delims=" %%x IN ('wmic process where "CommandLine Like '%%some text to match%%' and Caption='python.exe'" get caption') DO for /F "delims=" %%j in ("%%x") do (
```

should read:

```bat
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%x In ('"WMIC Process Where (Caption='%EXE%' And CommandLine Like '%%some text to match%%') Get Caption"') Do For /F "Delims=" %%j IN ("%%x") Do (
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I solved it in a different way, see my updated post